# Is it correct - クッキング・テール?

Tags: grammar, translation

I am starting a cooking blog which is named Cooking Tale. I wanted a person to translate the name and he said クッキング・テール is ok. But when I search for this name in dictionaries, it says "tail" not "tale". Is this a correct use?

Cooking Tale - クッキング・テール

Comment: How about 「[物語]{ものがたり}」 for "tale"... e.g. 『冬物語』(The Winter's Tale),  『二都物語』(A Tale of Two Cities), 『カンタベリー物語』(The Canterbury Tales), or maybe (a bit childlike)「お[話]{はなし}」e.g. 『ピーターラビットのおはなし』(The Tale of Peter Rabbit)

Comment: Not recommended. 99% of Japanese with some knowledge in English would misunderstand the title as "cooking tail". Again, 99% of Japanese cannot distinguish between "tale" and "story" so I'd recommend クッキングストーリー. It moderately sounds 外人ish

Answer (score 2):

The literal translation is 料理の話. I think クッキング will get through to Japanese people but テール as the word "tale" may not get through to them. As you found in your search, I think a lot of Japanese people may think テール is the word "しっぽ(tail)", or may not know テール.

Answer (score 1):

I think テイル be considered. Here are some Japanese transliterations that use that to transliterate `tale`:

- [Shark Tale](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BB%E3%83%86%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB)
- [Tales of Symphonia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%86%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BA_%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96_%E3%82%B7%E3%83%B3%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%8B%E3%82%A2)
- [TaleSpin](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%86%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3)

That said it seems both are in use. [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB) lists both フェアリー**テール** and フェアリー**テイル** as used to transliterate fairy tail and fairy tale.